# Drag and insert div into another div

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to design a feature that could drag and insert one div into another div.

For example:

`<div id="1"> </div>

 <div id="2"> </div>`

i want to make #1 draggable (I know it can be done with jQuery, so draggable is not part of my question), and drag #1 over #2, and when mouseup, #2 could be inserted into #1

```
<div id="1"> <div id="2"> </div> </div>
```

could somebody explain to me how to achieve that?

Comment: If `jQuery is not part of your question`, I'm beginning to feel that this is a homework.

Comment: Here is the demo for your reference http://jsfiddle.net/3fsVd/

Comment: @MightyPork i was only saying draggable is not part of my questions, not jQuery

Comment: @Dh... that's helpful, thanks!

Comment: @user2640254 yes, but I don't see any reason why you couldn't use jQuery-UI drggable if you can use jQuery.

Comment: @MightyPork well i did, my problem is that I cannot get the ID the div, which located in dropping area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simplify this quite a bit by using [jQuery UI's Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/3fsVd/8/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    addElements();
    $(function () {
        $("#list1, #list2").sortable({
            connectWith: ".lists",
            cursor: "move"
        }).disableSelection();
    });


});

function addElements() {
    $("#list1").empty().append(
        "<li id='item1' class='list1Items'>Item 1</li>" +
        "<li id='item2' class='list1Items'>Item 2</li>" +
        "<li id='item3' class='list1Items'>Item 3</li>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For demo : [Click Here](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)

Code :

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```